# CapForm bugged in V11?

Tags: graphics, bugs, mac-os-x

**Bug introduced in 10.4 and fixed in 11.1**

This problem is specific to OS X

---

It appears on my system (OSX 10.10.5) that `CapForm` isn't behaving itself in V11. Initially I thought it was a problem with the combination of `CapForm` and `VertexColors` but it seems even weirder than that!

For demonstration consider the four combinations of either `CapForm[Automatic]` or `CapForm["Round"]` with either no vertex colors or `VertexColors->{Red,Green}`:

```
t = Thickness[0.2];    
pr = PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 1.2}, {-0.2, 0.2}};

GraphicsGrid[{{
   Graphics[{CapForm[Automatic], t, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, pr],
   Graphics[{CapForm[Automatic], t, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, VertexColors -> {Red, Green}]}, pr]
 }, {
   Graphics[{CapForm["Round"], t, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, pr],
   Graphics[{CapForm["Round"], t, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, VertexColors -> {Red, Green}]}, pr]
 }}
]
```

**V10.3**

[image]

**V11**

[image]

As you can see, the rounded caps are not produced in V11.

However, perhaps even more bizarrely, if I run the third entry (rounded ends, no vertex colors) on it's own outside of `GraphicsGrid` it works fine:

```
Graphics[{t, CapForm["Round"], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, pr]
```

**V11**

[image]

Bugged?

**Addendum**

Perhaps a hint at the origin of this oddity is that when exported to a vector graphics format the rounded ends reappear! Although the vertex coloring is mutilated [as in past versions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97305/6588):

```
line = Graphics[{CapForm["Round"], t, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, VertexColors -> {Red, Green}]}, pr];
Export["~/Desktop/img31.pdf", %]
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine in V11 on Win 7 Ent SP1

Comment: I can confirm this behavior (Mathematica 11.0.0.0 on OS X 10.11.6)

Comment: Looks like this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IWgpv.png)

Comment: Did you already report this to support@wolfram.com?

Answer (score 4):

On 11.1 on mac osx.

```
t = Thickness[0.2];
pr = PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 1.2}, {-0.2, 0.2}};

GraphicsGrid[{
 {Graphics[{CapForm[Automatic], t, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, pr], 
  Graphics[{CapForm[Automatic], t, 
   Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, VertexColors -> {Red, Green}]}, pr]}, 
 {Graphics[{CapForm["Round"], t, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, pr], 
 Graphics[{CapForm["Round"], t, 
  Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, VertexColors -> {Red, Green}]}, pr]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: It's fixed! Yay! Thanks for checking and updating us.