# Exporting graphics with VertexColors problem

Tags: graphics, export, pdf-format

I've generated a graphics which exhibit gradient color in rectangle and export it as:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]; 
Export["./test.pdf", Graphics[{Polygon[{{-4, 5/3}, {-4, 0}, {4, 0}, {4, 5/3}}, 
VertexColors -> {RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 0.3], RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 1], 
  RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 1], RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 0.3]}]}]];
```

If I preview it, i.e., directly view in Mathematica GUI,

```
Graphics[{Polygon[{{-4, 5/3}, {-4, 0}, {4, 0}, {4, 5/3}}, 
VertexColors -> {RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 0.3], RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 1], 
  RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 1], RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 0.3]}]}]
```

I got
[image]
but the exported file looks like[image]
with a very peculiar slash line and an edge around the rectangle. I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Related: [(97305)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97305/121)